# Siri not able to recognise my app name if Siri setting language are in certain language

Tags: ios, swift, siri

Let's just say my app is called "ABC", if I say "ABC" to Siri (English settings), Siri will detect "ABC and the app will open. Same goes if it is in Japanese or Chinese Siri language settings. The problem is if I use language settings of for example Korean and Thai, it detects "ABC" but in its own language writing characters (ex. "알파벳") and it will no longer open the app. I have tried specifying my app name using CFBundleName, CFBundleDisplayName, CFBundleSpokenName, INAlternativeAppNames, and INAlternativeAppNamePronunciationHint and it still not working for some language. How can I make it work on those languages?

Comment: Did you add `INAlternativeAppNamePronunciationHint`?

Comment: Yes, I did add INAlternativeAppNamePronunciationHint together with INAlternativeAppName.